# Jar works properly only when launched from shell

Tags: shell, java-8, javafx-8, linux-mint

I'm making a project in Eclipse and building it with Gradle; my OS is Linux. Weird thing that when I create a folder in `/home/[myuser]/`, put the Jar into it and try to run it, it doesn't work properly; when I run it from shell, it works. Also it works if I just put it in `/home/[myuser]`. Is this problem related to permissions? My program tries to create 2 text files and read some other files on run.

Comment: what's the error message? how does it not work properly?

Comment: What exactly do you do when you "try to run it?" Running via shell (from the command line) apparently works, so you must be doing something different.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I either double-click on the jar or right-click and select "Open with Oracle Java 8 runtime".

Comment: @nlloyd It seems to unable to create necessary files for its configuration.

Comment: Have you tried to add debugging output to see why things go wrong? For example, show the exact error string when file creation fails, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution - just make shell scripts (.sh and .bat) to launch the program instead of launching the Jar directly.